# If function's argument be multiplied by a constant while keep the form of differential equation, then the solution must be the form of polynomial?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose a differential expression $\partial_x^2 f(x)+\frac{1}{x^2}f(x)=0$, 
my professor tole me that since a change of variable of the form $y=\lambda x$ will not change the form of expression. i.e. 
$\partial_y^2 f(y)+\frac{1}{y^2}f(y)=0$, thus the solution must be in the form of polynomial $x^{n}$ for some order $n$.

How to prove this statement, that when a multiply of constant to the argument of function does not change the form of differential equation, the solution must take the form of polynomial?

Comment: I think I could understood it in the region where there's distinct complex roots and justify it by uniqueness theorem, but what if there's roots with multiplicity not equal to 1? Does it still holds?

Answer (score 1):

Do you know about Euler-Cauchy ODE?

One can use $x^m$ as basis solution, for this equation you would then get the characteristic equation $$0=m(m-1)+1\implies 0=(2m-1)^2+3$$ so that $$m=\frac{1\pm i\sqrt3}2,$$ which is not exactly an integer. The resulting real combinations of the monomial basis solutions are $$\sqrt{x}\cos\left(\frac{\sqrt3}2\ln x\right)\text{ and }\sqrt{x}\sin\left(\frac{\sqrt3}2\ln x\right),$$
which also do not entirely fit the classical picture of a polynomial.

---

The claim of the task can be interpreted as: If $f(x)$ is a solution, then $g(x)=f(λx)$ is also a solution. If $\vec y=(y_1,y_2)^T$ is a solution basis, then this transformation leads to a matrix function $A(λ)$ so that $\vec y(λx)=A(λ)\vec y(x)$, so that also $\vec y(x)=A(x)\vec y(1)$. $A$ is multiplicative, $A(λ_1λ_2)=A(λ_1)A(λ_2)$, so that for instance $A(λ^n)=A(λ)^n$. In this sense $A$ behaves like a monomial, but it is still a matrix.

Comment: So, basically, when the root does not have higher multiplicity then it hold by uniqueness?(why it seemed has to exclude the root of unity as well?)

Comment: I do not understand what you mean? What root of unity and where is it excluded? You can always substitute $x=e^t$ to get a linear ODE with constant coefficients, from where you can import the rules for multiple roots of the characteristic equation.

Comment: I mean with equivalence class of roots of unity or multiplicity bigger than one, the statement was nolonger valid.

Comment: No, still not clear. The claim of the task is, as shown, questionable, so the question is not where you can invalidate it, but in which sense it could be valid at all. Can you put your suspicions in some formulas, they tend to be more universally understandable.

Comment: Aside, TH example you game of $m$ still fell into the region of polynomials, it's just a Euler identity manipulation. The example stilled worked for roots with multiplicity $=1$. The complex roots doesn't affect the result.